# Convert bases in MATLAB for non-integers

Tags: matlab

I am looking to convert 45653.127664 which is in the octal base, to hexadecimal, binary and decimal.

How can this be done using MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions to do this,, try out different combinations of `base2dec, dec2base`

Comment: Thnaks, but these functions do not support fractions, only integers.

Comment: check out "Fixed-Point Toolbox",,,     

http://www.mathworks.com/products/fixed/